# How to create a walkable crate box?

Tags: unity, 2d, platformer

I have a 2D platformer with each platform having a `PlatformEffector2D` component. I want to create a crate that can be pushed.

When I jump into the edge of the crate, my player gets stuck, so I added `PlatformEffector2D` to the crate. But when the crate has a `PlatformEffector2D` component it falls below the platform.

I can remove the component and add a `Physics2D` Material with zero friction to prevent the player from getting stuck in the crate's edge, but I can't walk above the crate (because the zero friction). The images below illustrate it.

Player getting stuck in the edge of the crate that don't have `PlatformEffector2D`.

[image]

If it has a `PlatformEffector2D` it will fall below the platform.

[image]

My objects have the following components (when the player gets stuck at the edge of a crate):

- `Player (BoxCollider2D, Rigidbody2D)`
- `Crate (BoxCollider2D, Rigidbody2D)`
- `Platform (EdgeCollider2D, PlatformEffector2D)`

What should I do so my player can push the crate and walk above the crate? Would anyone happen to have a sample script?

FYI: I use Physics2D.OverlapCircle to detect the ground. (Unity 5.4.0)

Answer (score 3):

Finally I fixed it. I added two empty `GameObject`s to check the right and left side of the player. Now he can push the crate and walk above it without being stuck at the edge of the crate.

```
// Check if player is on the ground or not
grounded = Physics2D.OverlapCircle (groundCheck.position, groundRadius, whatIsGround);
rightSided = Physics2D.OverlapCircle (rightSideCheck.position, groundRadius, whatIsGround);
leftSided = Physics2D.OverlapCircle (leftSideCheck.position, groundRadius, whatIsGround);

// Movement
if (!grounded && (rightSided || leftSided)) {
    // Do nothing
} else {
    // Handle movement input
}
```

[image]